# display: flex making my cards uneven, how can I fix that?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

for some reason after adding flex-wrap: wrap; and removing it after, my display: flex on the cards seems to be uneven.

```css
#prices {
  display: flex;
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="prices">
  <ul class="listdrop">
    <li class="card-head">Intermediate</li>

    <li>Get Big</li>
    <li>Get Strong</li>
    <li>Feel good</li>
    <li class="pay">300$</li>
    <li>
      <button type="button" class="butn">Buy</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

How can I fix this?
appreciate the help thanks
https://codepen.io/picklemyrickle/full/XWjzyvb

```
</section>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .cards {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      .card1 ul li {
        list-style: none;
      }

      .card1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      ul {
        padding: 10px 19px;
      }

      .card1 li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .card-head {
        color: white;
        background-color: #4b6584;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 25px;
      }

      .list-drop {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
        transition: 0.3s;
        border: 1px solid;
        list-style-type: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card1">
        <ul class="list-drop">
          <li class="card-head">Beginner</li>
          <li>get big</li>
          <li>get strong</li>
          <li>feel good</li>
          <li>100 $</li>
          <li><button>buy</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="card1">
        <ul class="list-drop">
          <li class="card-head">Beginner</li>
          <li>get big</li>
          <li>get strong</li>
          <li>feel good</li>
          <li>100 $</li>
          <li><button>buy</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="card1">
        <ul class="list-drop">
          <li class="card-head">Beginner</li>
          <li>get big</li>
          <li>get strong</li>
          <li>feel good</li>
          <li>100 $</li>
          <li><button>buy</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```